# Is there any problem using deprecated NumPy API?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to pass numpy array to c++, but there is a deprecated numpy API and I don't know where to find the substitute.
It shows me a warning message when I build my c++ code to make library.

numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

Is there any problem to use deprecated API? If I use it, it runs only once and just quit my program without any further error/warning message(this cfunc should run many times in a loop in my python code that imports c library.). Of course if I disabled deprecated API, it just tells me that it cannot find that API.

Here is a part of my code to receive numpy array and convert it to double array to handle it in c++

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy\ndarraytypes.h"
#include "numpy\ndarrayobject.h"
#include "numpy\arrayobject.h"

static PyObject* cfunc(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
PyArrayObject* numpyarray;
double* carray;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &numpyarray))
{
return NULL;
}
carray = (double*)numpyarray->data; // When I build this code, it says 'data' is not a member of 'tagPyArrayObject'
```

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thank you so much!

Best wishes,
JESuh

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject):

> Direct access to the struct fields are deprecated. Use the `PyArray_*(arr)` form instead.

For `data`, that's [`PyArray_DATA(arr)`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/array.html#c.PyArray_DATA). Note that there is no guarantee that a NumPy array is contiguous (or one-dimensional), and you're not doing any safety checks. Naively indexing the array's buffer is unsafe.

As for the problems with using deprecated APIs, deprecated APIs may be removed in future NumPy releases.

Comment: Thank you so much! PyArray_DATA(PyArrayObject* arr) works well :)